# Unable to build a regex to match the article tag

Tags: c#, regex, selenium

I have been trying to create a regex to match the article tag and get all the text .

Here is my article tag-

```
<article id="post-82" class="post-82 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-publishing">
        <div class="entry-content clearfix">        
                         <div class="abh_box abh_box_up abh_box_drop-down"><ul class="abh_tabs"> <li class="abh_about abh_active">
<p>With India playing host,</p>
    <footer class="entry-meta-bar clearfix"><div class="entry-meta clearfix">
               <span class="comments"><a href="http://www.test.com/blog/emerging-markets/#respond">No Comments</a></span>           

      </div></footer>
    </article>
```

I need everything which is inside the article tag.So far I have tried the following Regex-

```
<article (.*?)</article>

 (?:<article>)(.*?)(?:</article>)
```

None of them works .Please help.

Comment: That's because regex is the wrong tool for the job of parsing HTML. You'll never get it working perfectly. Use an HTML parser (HtmlAgilityPack works) and win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing of HTML. Use Html parser like Html Agility pack

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("article").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
<[article][^>]*>((.|\n)*?)<\/article>
```

https://regex101.com/r/oOJ9bt/2

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use regex for something like this and you don't need to load an XML parser. Just use `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` on the element you want the contained HTML for.

For example, this gets only the article element in your supplied HTML by ID.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("post-82")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

This gets the HTML for all articles on the page.

```
for (WebElement article : driver.findElements(By.tagName("article")))
{
    System.out.println(article.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}
```